# Chrome Extension: Get tweets from Twitter home page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get tweets on my timeline using a Chrome Extension.

I'm selecting elements using the following query -

```
const tweets = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='tweetText']");
```

I'm running this in the contentScript.js at 'document_idle'

I keep getting an empty NodeList.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Mute",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Chrome Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Mute"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", 
    "scripting"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://twitter.com/home"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": [
        "contentScript.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Twitter builds the page after document_idle. Use MutationObserver to detect the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample MutationObserver.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "MutationObserver",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```js
console.log("MutationObserver:Start");

const onMutation = (mutations) => {
  // mo.disconnect();
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node) {
        if (node.dataset && node.dataset.testid) {
          // console.log("node.dataset.testid=" + node.dataset.testid)
          if (node.dataset.testid == "cellInnerDiv") {
            const tweets = node.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='tweetText']");
            console.log(tweets);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // observe();
}

const observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

observe();
```